# ProductFlavors Configuration

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-espresso, android-productflavors

I configured a constant in the build.gradle of the application I developed.
It is an "End-Point" constant for API calls.
When I'm developing in the development environment, the application calls an "End-Point", when I'm developing in the production environment the application calls another "End-Point".
Now comes the problem, when I'm developing the tests for the application, the configuration is not working to pick up the End-Point Correctly.
Can someone help me?

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        buildConfigField STRING, API_URL, '"https://end-point-production/"'
    }
    debug {
        buildConfigField STRING, API_URL, '"https://end-point-dev/"'
    }
}

productFlavors {
    ui_tests {
        buildConfigField STRING, API_URL, '"http://end-point-tests/"'
    }
}

public class BaseController {

// Service url.
protected static final String API_URL = BuildConfig.API_URL;

/**
 * Crates a basic retrofit request.
 *
 * @return Retrofit request.
 */
public static Retrofit getRetrofit() {
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    client.setConnectTimeout(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    client.setReadTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    client.setWriteTimeout(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    return new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(API_URL)
            .client(client)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(new GsonBuilder()
                    .excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation()
                    .create()))
            .build();
    }
 }


@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    server = new MockWebServer();
    server.start(8681);

    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    client.setConnectTimeout(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    client.setReadTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    client.setWriteTimeout(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(API_URL)
            .client(client)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(new GsonBuilder()
                    .excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation()
                    .create()))
            .build();
}
```

[image: UiTests Environment]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to do like this:

**There is an additional flavor**

```
productFlavors {
    non_test {
    }
    ui_tests {
        buildConfigField STRING, API_URL, '"http://end-point-tests/"'
    }
}

applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        println("Iterating variant: " + variant.getName())

            if (variant.getName() == "ui_testsRelease") {
                buildConfigField STRING, API_URL, '"https://end-point-production/"'
            } else if (variant.getName() == "ui_testsDebug") {
                buildConfigField STRING, API_URL, '"http://end-point-tests/"'

            } else if (variant.getName() == "non_testRelease"){
                buildConfigField STRING, API_URL, '"https://end-point-production/"'
            } else if (variant.getName() == "non_testDebug") {
                buildConfigField STRING, API_URL, '"https://end-point-dev/"'

            }
        }
```

or for example(it looks a little better):

**just move** `ui_tests` **from** `productFlavors` **to** `buildTypes`

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        buildConfigField STRING, API_URL, '"https://end-point-production/"'
    }
    debug {
        buildConfigField STRING, API_URL, '"https://end-point-dev/"'
    }
    ui_tests {
        buildConfigField STRING, API_URL, '"http://end-point-tests/"'
    }
}
```

Comment: I have chosen to use in my application 3 buildTypes, realese, debug and uiTest.
My application has another problem, when I change in my application the BuildVariant for uiTest the test libraries (Espresso and JUnit) stop working. Can you help me with this?

Comment: I suggest to you create a new question on SO about this. You do well-designed questions.